# Confused about MultiHeadAttention output shapes (Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, transformer-model, multihead-attention

```
random_time = np.random.random([1,1,100])
random_2 = np.random.random([1,100,1])
out_attention = MultiHeadAttention(
        num_heads = 4,
        key_dim = 1,
        #output_shape=400
    )
output = out_attention(random_2,random_2)
output = Dense(1,activation = 'ReLU')(output)
print(output)
```

Hi, I am playing around with the code above since I have been tasked with creating a transformer for 1D time-series data.

The issue is that out_attention(random_2,random_time), out_attention(random_time,random_2), out_attention(random_time,random_time) and out_attention(random_2,random_2) all give valid outputs but with different shape. The code above gives me a tensor with the shape (1, 400, 1). I would expect the correct code to give me a tensor with shape (1,1,1), and I can do that by choosing (random_time, random_time)... But, that doesn't seem to fit with my interpretation of the [official documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/attention_layers/multi_head_attention/) for the layer.

The Attention is All You Need paper also says:

> In addition to attention sub-layers, each of the layers in our encoder
> and decoder contains a fully connected feed-forward network, which is
> applied to each position separately and identically

This seems to imply that my implementation above is the right one for a transformer.

However, this seems to transfer to all layers downstream... So, every layer will have at least 100 tokens. I can potentially find somewhat of an explanation in the Tensorflow transformer [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/transformer#run_inference). There it states:

> Note: The model is optimized for efficient training and makes a
> next-token prediction for each token in the output simultaneously.
> This is redundant during inference, and only the last prediction is
> used. This model can be made more efficient for inference if you only
> calculate the last prediction when running in inference mode
> (training=False).

Their model seem to be using similar layers.. So, is that what I am supposed to do? Just ignore 99 of the outputs and focus on the last one? The Vaswani et al paper after all states that it produces tokens "one element at a time".

Finally, the output_shape parameter brings even more confusion; It seems to be able to reshape the output of the MultiHeadAttention into any shape....

Is there any good resource on how to understand this layer? Or, do I just have to dig through every line of the source code to figure out what it actually does..?